# How to install lettuce library on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, redis, lettuce

How to install lettuce library on Android studio in Gradle files ?

https://lettuce.io

is there any solution to compile the library ?

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0’
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the lettuce's [getting started](https://lettuce.io/docs/getting-started.html) section there is a section called **For Gradle Users** on how to add the library from gradle. I think just adding:

```
implementation 'io.lettuce:lettuce-core:5.1.3.RELEASE'
```

would work. You must check if you must adjust your current dependencies and/or modify your `proguard` rules.

Hope I helped.

Comment: Working you are a life saver !!! thanks a lot ,now quick question do you think that lettuce is better than Jedis or ?